# Prerequisites for Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: self-study, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have read several "intuitive" introductions to LDA. However, I now want to learn it properly.

I have already read through most of Duda, and that was my introduction to data science. However, I reckon I need more to understand LDA. What should I read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some resources:

- Video lectures by [David Blei](http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_blei_tm/) on LDA topic modeling.
- Gibbs sampling for inferring topics from scientific articles by [Tom
  Griffiths](http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/papers/sciencetopics.pdf)
- Original paper on latent Dirichlet allocation by [David Blei and
  Andrew Ng](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf)

Once you understand these papers, play with LDA on some text data. LDA is a generative model, which means you can generate your own sample data and run LDA

- [Gensim python package](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/)
- [Matlab topic modeling
  toolbox](http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/programs_data/toolbox.htm)

Good luck!